# Starting gnome-shell with different home

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, home-directory

In the company I work for we have home directories mounted by network filesystem. Like all networks our lan can be slow or unreliable at times. Most of my system deals with this kind of situation but gnome freezes completely and evenn when the network is back it still takes unreasonably long time to come back round.

An ideal solution would be to find a way to run a gnome session that has the correct notion of $HOME but uses system local `~/.local` and `~/.cache` (and whatever directories it uses).

My distro is ubuntu but I am hoping for a distribution agnostic solution.

EDIT:

```
 $ fuser ~            
/homes/cperivol:      1988c  2040c  2063c  2075c  2197c  2198c  2235c  2298c  2299c  2328c  2378c  2385c  2402c  2543c  2582c  2662c
 $ ps aux | grep gnome   
cperivol  1977  0.0  0.0 369492  3980 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
cperivol  1988  0.0  0.2 391104 10396 ?        Ssl  16:53   0:00 gnome-session --session=gnome
cperivol  2023  0.0  0.0  12572   324 ?        Ss   16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=gnome
cperivol  2026  0.0  0.0  24480   540 ?        S    16:53   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=gnome
cperivol  2040  0.1  0.5 783104 23132 ?        Sl   16:53   0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
cperivol  2063  0.0  0.1 369692  4700 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-printer
cperivol  2075  1.6  3.0 1793504 123240 ?      Sl   16:53   0:15 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
cperivol  2235  0.0  0.2 421908 10676 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-calendar-server
cperivol  2246  0.0  0.3 398160 13772 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon
cperivol  2298  0.0  0.2 306376  9448 ?        Sl   16:53   0:00 gnome-screensaver
cperivol  2543  0.2  0.4 592516 19312 ?        Sl   16:55   0:02 gnome-terminal
cperivol  2548  0.0  0.0  12708   888 ?        S    16:55   0:00 gnome-pty-helper
cperivol  2916  0.0  0.0  13592   928 pts/1    S+   17:09   0:00 grep gnome
```

And also right after I plug ethernet out and back in

```
 $ tail ~/.xsession-errors
Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x1e00003 (Messaging )
Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.
Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x1e00003 (Messaging )
Window manager warning: meta_window_activate called by a pager with a 0 timestamp; the pager needs to be fixed.

(gnome-settings-daemon:2040): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_variant_get_int32: assertion `g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
WARNING:root:timeout reached, exiting
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x240008b (Gmail - An) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
Window manager warning: Got a request to focus 0x240008b (XDG Base D) with a timestamp of 0.  This shouldn't happen!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directories can be controlled using the variables defined in the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html).

The variables relevant for you are `$XDG_DATA_HOME`, `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` and `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`.

The usual default values are:

`XDG_CONFIG_HOME`:  `~/.config`

`XDG_DATA_HOME`: `~/.local/share`

`XDG_CACHE_HOME`:  `~/.cache`

Not sure what's the best place to set them, but `.profile` comes to mind. Make sure to export the variables too.

Comment: You solution made things generally faster but once I disconnect ethernet it freezes after a while. I am guessing dbus is the problem, see edit

Comment: Is there anything else remote besides the home dir?

Comment: Nevermind, i had to disable filemanager manging my desktop. Everything works fine now, thanx!